# Using Trace32 & Lauterbach with CMD or Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, cmd, flash-memory, trace32, lauterbach

I have a group of .cmm files that I am flashing. Are there any good resources to explain how I can use Trace32 via either the cmd prompt (Windows) or Linux terminal?

My aim is to be able to automate flashing of the .cmm files without the GUI provided.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883140/controlling-trace32-via-command-line

Comment: ...and maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895207/controlling-lauterbach-through-command-line
...and that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074701/trace32-lauterbach-apis-for-c-program-access-to-the-application-variables